# Convert SVG to GeoJSON

Tags: svg, leaflet, geospatial, geojson

Is there a way to convert SVG files, e.g: [World_map_-_low_resolution.svg](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/80/World_map_-_low_resolution.svg)
into a GeoJSON which then can be loaded into Leaflet as a polygon?

Answer (score 4):

Want to know something cool? When Leaflet creates a polygon, it is an SVG. So try adding this SVG directly to the DOM in one of the Leaflet panes.

Comment: I would prefer to avoid hacking it. But it is an alternative, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use Inkscape to convert to DXF which can then be loaded into QGIS but it's really hard to do well because of all the complications:

Reference: [QGis: How to import svg or raster images into Quantum GIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691541/qgis-how-to-import-svg-or-raster-images-into-quantum-gis)

Why not use an open source GeoJSON file of the world boundaries like https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json/blob/master/countries.geo.json or if you need higher detail the natural earth vectors found here:https://github.com/nvkelso/natural-earth-vector/tree/master/geojson

Comment: Thank you for the geojson link, that really helps!  However, in the future I need to parse a bmp file to svg and then make a geojson out of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use svg-to-json for converting your SVG to JSON.
https://github.com/stela5/svg2json. I am not sure if this returns a GeoJSON but you could always parse the output of svg2json and create a valid GeoJSON out of it.

Answer (score 0):

This converter tool can be pretty useful: [mygeodata.cloud](https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/svg-to-geojson)